# Exchange 2016 User Mailbox listed as public folder in outlook 2010

Tags: exchange, public-folders

Weird thing happen.

I have public folder_ABC and my outlook listed this public folder_ABC in the folder list. After I removed public folder_ABC using ECP but the public folder mailboxes for public folder_ABC still exist in ECP.

Issue happened when i tried to add reminder@contonso.com mailbox into my outlook, it listed as screenshot below.
[image]

I deleted the Public folder_ABC in ECP and it is listed as disabled in EMC now.

But my mailbox and data@contonso.com is still listed as public folder when click on folder list in outlook 2010...

Comment: Do you have all service packs and updates applied to the MS Outlook 2010 client?

Comment: Hi @JozefIzso I'm using outlook 2010 version 14.0.7015, should be latest version?

Answer (score 0):

According to your issue, I found a thread which is simliar with yours and you could refer to Perry_Pan's replies in it: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/714f0cbc-bd4d-491f-b87a-a7979128761b/exchange-2016-public-folder-problem?forum=Exch2016GD

Hope everything goes well with you!